# expansion of linear transformation

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $X,Z$ linear spaces over $F$ and $Y$ a subspace of $X$ and $T\in L(Y,Z)$. Prove that there exists an $S\in L(X,Z)$ consisting an extension of $T$.

Comment: Do you mean an extension of T? And are your spaces finite dimensional?

Comment: Yes sorry! Extension. And no, not necessarily finite dimensional.

Comment: Why can't you compose T with the projection of X onto Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a basis $B$ of $Y$. Since $B$ is linearly independent over $F$, it can be extended to a basis of $X$, that is, there exists $B^*\supset B$ such that $B^*$ is a basis of $X$. Define $Sx=Tx$ if $x\in B$ and give it some arbitrary value for $x\in B^*\setminus B$. Extend $S$ to all of $X$ by linearity.

Comment: Could you please explain "by linearity"?

Comment: @christinelmp. A linear transformation is completely determined by its values on a basis; that is, given any map $f:B^*\to Z$ there exists an unique linear transformation $\phi:X\to Z$ such that $\phi(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in B^*$.